# Unknown Entity namespace alias in symfony2

Tags: orm, symfony, annotations, doctrine-orm

Hey I have two bundles in my symfony2 project. one is Bundle and the other one is PatentBundle.

My app/config/route.yml file is

```
MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:
resource: "@MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation
prefix:   /
defaults:  { _controller: "MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:Default:index" }

MunichInnovationGroupBundle:
resource: "@MunichInnovationGroupBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation
prefix:   /v1
defaults:  { _controller: "MunichInnovationGroupBundle:Patent:index" }

login_check:
pattern:   /login_check

logout:
pattern:   /logout
```

inside my controller i have

```
<?php
namespace MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use JMS\SecurityExtraPatentBundle\Annotation\Secure;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\Log;
use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\UserPatent;
use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\PmPortfolios;
use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\UmUsers;
use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\PmPatentgroups;
use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Form\PortfolioType;
use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Util\SecurityHelper;
use Exception;
/**
 * Portfolio controller.
 * @Route("/portfolio")
 */
class PortfolioController extends Controller {
/**
 * Index action.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="v2_pm_portfolio")
 * @Template("MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:Portfolio:index.html.twig")
 */
   public function indexAction(Request $request) {
    $portfolios = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:PmPortfolios')
    ->findBy(array('user' => '$user_id'));

           // rest of the method
  }
```

**Edit:**

My Entity Class

```
<?php

 namespace MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

  /**
  * MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\PmPortfolios
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="pm_portfolios")
  * @ORM\Entity
  */
  class PmPortfolios
  {
/**
 * @var string $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", length=36, nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $portfolioName
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="portfolio_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $portfolioName;

/**
 * @var text $description
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var string $permalink
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="permalink", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $permalink;

/**
 * @var string $sharingCode
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="sharing_code", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $sharingCode;

/**
 * @var boolean $shared
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="shared", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
private $shared;

/**
 * @var integer $sharedPortfolioCalls
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="shared_portfolio_calls", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $sharedPortfolioCalls;

/**
 * @var boolean $isDefault
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_default", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
private $isDefault;

/**
 * @var UmUsers
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UmUsers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $user;



/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set portfolioName
 *
 * @param string $portfolioName
 */
public function setPortfolioName($portfolioName)
{
    $this->portfolioName = $portfolioName;
}

/**
 * Get portfolioName
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPortfolioName()
{
    return $this->portfolioName;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param text $description
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return text 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set permalink
 *
 * @param string $permalink
 */
public function setPermalink($permalink)
{
    $this->permalink = $permalink;
}

/**
 * Get permalink
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPermalink()
{
    return $this->permalink;
}

/**
 * Set sharingCode
 *
 * @param string $sharingCode
 */
public function setSharingCode($sharingCode)
{
    $this->sharingCode = $sharingCode;
}

/**
 * Get sharingCode
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSharingCode()
{
    return $this->sharingCode;
}

/**
 * Set shared
 *
 * @param boolean $shared
 */
public function setShared($shared)
{
    $this->shared = $shared;
}

/**
 * Get shared
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getShared()
{
    return $this->shared;
}

/**
 * Set sharedPortfolioCalls
 *
 * @param integer $sharedPortfolioCalls
 */
public function setSharedPortfolioCalls($sharedPortfolioCalls)
{
    $this->sharedPortfolioCalls = $sharedPortfolioCalls;
}

/**
 * Get sharedPortfolioCalls
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getSharedPortfolioCalls()
{
    return $this->sharedPortfolioCalls;
}

/**
 * Set isDefault
 *
 * @param boolean $isDefault
 */
public function setIsDefault($isDefault)
{
    $this->isDefault = $isDefault;
}

/**
 * Get isDefault
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getIsDefault()
{
    return $this->isDefault;
}

/**
 * Set user
 *
 * @param MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\UmUsers $user
 */
public function setUser(\MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\UmUsers $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Get user
 *
 * @return MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\UmUsers 
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}
```

}

My bundle main class: MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle.php

```
 <?php

  namespace MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle;

  use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

  class MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle extends Bundle
 {
 }
```

when i try to load localhost/web/app_dev.php/portfolio

It says

```
   Unknown Entity namespace alias 'MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle'.
```

I am unable to figure out this error 
please help me if anyone has any idea I googled it a lot :(

Thanks in advance
       500 Internal Server Error - ORMException

Comment: Try to check your PmPortfolios entity, if the namespace is correct.

Comment: Another possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145101/how-to-address-the-bundle-in-php-app-console-generatedoctrinecrud

Answer (score 32):

Please, check your config.yml.

Reviewed in section `mappings` of `entity_managers`.
You should have something like `MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle: ~`

That is:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            defaults:
                mappings:
                    MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle: ~
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be enough with **auto_mapping: true**?

Comment: I just had this problem removing the default auto_mapping = true in my SF 2.3 app's config in order to add the stof/doctrineextensionsbundle mapping after SF2 threw an exception that auto_mapping wasn't a valid child. Re-adding auto_mapping as a sibling of the 'mappings' node (child of 'defaults' instead of a direct child of 'orm') above fixes the issues.

Comment: this answer is solved my problem. SF, see namespaces through that controller and start build entities properly.  full description in that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37652091/5809937

Answer (score 8):

In my case I was missing namespace name in the security.yml under providers

I had:

`entity: { class: AdministratorBundle:AdminUser }`

and needed to have:

`entity: { class: NamespaceAdministratorBundle:AdminUser }`

Comment: I forgot that the root class of the bundle includes the namespace at the beginning of its name. Thanks!

Example for others: The root class for `Company\MyBundle` is `CompanyMyBundle`, not `MyBundle`.

Answer (score 7):

If you use 2 or more entity managers -- you need to specify manager also
**getManager('YourManager')**

```
$repository = 
    $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager('YourManager')
    ->getRepository('YourBundle:YourEntity');
```

Comment: This answer should be moved above. As i almost lost hope and then i tried this solution and it worked.

Comment: You Sir have just saved my day! I've been pulling my hair out over this for the last two days.

Answer (score 2):

Check you bundle logical name (MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle). Bundle logical name is name of main class of your bundle, e.g. JobsBundle

and provide your entity sourcecode.

Comment: when I changed my query to 
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager('pp_userdat');
em->->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:PmPortfolios')
    ->findBy(array('user' => '$user_id'));
then it gives me some Proxy error in ORM

Comment: Fatal error: Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory::getProxy() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:/wamp/www/idp/app/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies\MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundleEntityUmUsersProxy.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\idp\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory.php on line 85

Comment: check app/cache folder permissions, maybe it can help

Comment: and I suggest you to create another question with this error if you won't solve it quickly

Answer (score 1):

Documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database) states you can use the string **`'MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:PmPortfolios'`** as shortcut to **`'MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle\Entity\PmPortfolios'`** as long as your entity lives under the Entity namespace of your bundle.

Your bundle is **MunichInnovationGroupBundle** so instead of

```
->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:PmPortfolios')
```

use

```
->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle\Entity\PmPortfolios')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try being more explicit in your config.yml file by adding some fields:

```
orm:
    ...

    mappings:
        MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:
                type: annotation
                dir: "MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle/Controller"
                is_bundle: true
                prefix: MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle
                alias: MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle
        [more mappings..]
```

Comment: I was just about to add a response like this one, it worked for me with this approach, but not until I changed `alias:` to anything different from `MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle` say: `alias: MunichInnovation`

Answer (score 1):

Please, check your config.yml + AppKernel.php

**config.yml** must be

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
```

or replace **auto_mapping** with

```
    mappings:
        StoreShopBundle: ~
```

for more, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37652091/5809937

in **AppKernel.php**
don't forget to check if bundle is activated:

```
        new MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle(),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this when tried to use bandle name without core folder name. It was in config/security.yml

Folder structure in my case is the next src/Dp/UserBundle/....

I changed this 
`providers:

```
    main:
        entity: { class: UserBundle:User, property: username }`
```

to this 
`providers:

```
    main:
        entity: { class: DpUserBundle:User, property: username }`
```

So copy name of unknown Entity name and search each entries in project, check - they have to be with folder prefix (Dp in my case)

Answer (score 0):

As at Symfony version 2.3.7, I used NameofCompanySomethingBundle:EntityRequired e.g.  AcmeBlogBundle:User and it works.

auto-mapping: true (default) was used under orm: in config.yml.

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur if you use multiple entity managers and you do not specify the entity manager in your controller function.

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.//your_entity_manager_name_here//_entity_manager');
$dql   = "SELECT ...";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

open your app\config.yml, must be

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
replace to
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
              MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle: ~
```