# How to address the bundle in php app/console generate:doctrine:crud

Tags: symfony, doctrine, crud

In my symfony 2 project I have a bundle at

```
src/Cinergy/Bundle/PeopleServiceBundle
```

Now I'd like to generate a CRUD controller based on a doctrine entity, but I'm constantly failing to enter the correct string for the entity parameter.

I tried things like:

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:crud --entity=Cinergy/Bundle/PeopleServiceBundle:Group
```

or

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:crud --entity=@PeopleServiceBundle:Group
```

All of them return erros like:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]                             
Unknown Entity namespace alias '@PeopleServiceBundle'.
```

What's the right syntax for the `--entity` parameter? Or is there something missing after all?

This is how the directory structure looks right now:

```
src/Cinergy/Bundle/PeopleServiceBundle/
├── Controller
│   ├── GroupController.php
│   └── PersonController.php
├── DependencyInjection
│   ├── Configuration.php
│   └── PeopleServiceExtension.php
├── PeopleServiceBundle.php
├── Resources
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── routing.yml
│   │   └── services.yml
│   ├── doc
│   │   └── index.rst
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── images
│   │   └── js
│   ├── translations
│   │   └── messages.fr.xliff
│   └── views
│       └── Default
│           └── index.html.twig
└── Tests
    └── Controller
        ├── GroupControllerTest.php
        └── PersonControllerTest.php
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After all it turned out that I have to create the entity before I can create the CRUD controller for it. Of course that makes sense. Unfortunately the [Sensio Generator Bundle documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html) does list the operations in the oposite order which pushed me into the wrong direction.

This means the correct order ist

1. [Generating a New Bundle Skeleton](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_bundle.html)
2. [Generating a New Doctrine Entity Stub](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_entity.html)
3. [Generating a CRUD Controller Based on a Doctrine Entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to register your bundle into your `AppKernel`.

Then simply run the following command.
Don't put `@` before the bundle's name

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:crud --entity=PeopleServiceBundle:Group
```

More about [generating a CRUD controller based on a Doctrine entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html).

Comment: This returns the same error message: [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException] Unknown Entity namespace alias 'PeopleServiceBundle'.

Answer (score 1):

According to the symfony docs, you have to use " The entity name given as a  shortcut notation containing the bundle name  in which the entity is located and the name of tvhe entity", so it should be something like

```
--entity=CinergyPeopleServiceBundle:Group
```

Comment: This returns [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException] Unknown Entity namespace alias 'CinergyPeopleServiceBundle'.

Comment: What is the name of the Bundle? how is the file at src/Cinergy/Bundle/PeopleServiceBundle named?

Comment: I added the current directory tree in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one Bundle and want to use different database connection just update your config.yml and parameters.yml by adding configuration and parameters.

This will solve problem with CRUD generation.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for hours until I found out that in my app/config/config.yml under doctrine.orm I removed `auto_mapping: true` which caused the issue. This may be useful for other people :)

Comment: Of course, don't miss to run app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Answer (score 0):

If it still relevant for someone :)
guys, it's because DoctrineBundle DoctrineExtension compile the list of valid aliases based on all registered bundles, that have 'Entity' (or other configured) folder in them.

So in order to use doctrine:generate:crud or generate:doctrine:crud,
you have to create just folder Entity in your bundle, and not required to create entity first (as command says - it's true).

So you it will work if you already have some entity in your bundle,
or if you have just empty Entity folder in your bundle.