# Generating a CRUD Controller in a different bundle

Tags: symfony, crud

I want to generate some CRUD controllers with the following command:

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:crud
```

my problem is that I made 2 bundles (1 front end and 1 for the admin section) my entities are in the defaultbundle, but I'd like to generate the CRUD controllers in my admin bundle, is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to address the bundle in php app/console generate:doctrine:crud](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145101/how-to-address-the-bundle-in-php-app-console-generatedoctrinecrud)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't think this is a duplicate, I already created my entities in the default bundle, now I want to generate crud controllers of these entities in my adminbundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generating CRUD controllers in a bundle different of the entity's one is, as far as I know, impossible.

Indeed, CRUD controllers generator is just here for test. But if you really want to use it, you can actually copy the controller, views and form in the other bundle. You'll just need to change the templates' paths and the namespaces at the beginning of the controller and the Form type.

Comment: Figured as much, copying them over to the other bundle is what I did so far, but it's easy to miss something when renaming ofcourse.