# Symfony doctrine auto_mapping Unrecognized

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, sonata

I have added SonataUserBundle and it is giving error

config.yml

```
doctrine: 
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
                    SonataUserBundle: ~
```

error

> Unrecognized options "naming_strategy, auto_mapping, dql" under
>   "doctrine.orm"

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You are mixing shortened and full configuration.

If you just want to use the default entity manager then you can place everything under the `orm` key (the shortened config). This will be remapped so that it is under `doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default` by the bundle extension.

If, however, you want to chaneg the name of the entity manager or use multiples then you would need to use the full configuration specifying each entity manager.

<kbd>Shortened Config</kbd>

```
doctrine: 
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
            SonataUserBundle: ~
```

<kbd>Full Config</kbd>

```
doctrine: 
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
                    SonataUserBundle: ~
```

Comment: I cannot edit as it is a too short edit but the auto_generate_proxy_classes needs to be under orm not entities managers.

Answer (score 2):

Do you think it is necessary to configure the mappings manually if you set auto_mapping to true?

Doctrine's auto_mapping feature loads annotation configuration from the Entity/ directory of each bundle and looks for other formats (e.g. YAML, XML) in the Resources/config/doctrine directory.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#custom-mapping-entities-in-a-bundle