# Symfony 4 Sonata Media Bundle Installation

Tags: sonata-media-bundle, symfony4

I have a few errors during installation of Sonata Media Bundle on Symfony 4 application which had no place with Symfony 2.8.

The first error:

```
 sensio/generator-bundle v3.1.6 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.7|~3.0
```

Next one, after solving the previous:

```
- php-amqplib/php-amqplib v2.7.0 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
```

Another one:

```
Unrecognized options "naming_strategy, auto_mapping, mappings" under "doctrine.orm"
```

And then, when I tried to clear the cache:

```
Class Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\ApplicationSonataMediaBundle not found in home/user/projects/svoya-fignia/config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/home/user/projects/svoya-fignia/config/services.yaml").
```

or this one

```
Class Sonata\MediaBundle\PHPCR\BaseGalleryHasMediaRepository not found in home/user/projects/svoya-fignia/config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/home/user/projects/svoya-fignia/config/services.yaml").
```

Answer (score 7):

I found the solutions for all of them, but it took some time, so I want to post it here for everyone who encounter this problem.

The first error with `sensio/generator-bundle` is solved by requiring dev version of `sonata-media-bundle`:

```
composer require sonata-project/media-bundle:3.x-dev
```

Solution for the next one is obvious, but anyway:

```
sudo yum install php-bcmath
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install php-bcmath
```

Unrecognized options problem is solved here: [Symfony doctrine auto_mapping Unrecognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634625/symfony-doctrine-auto-mapping-unrecognized)

And finally the problem with classes that are not found is caused by symfony autowiring and should be solved by adding `Application` directory to excluded ones:

```
# services.yaml
services:
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Application}'
```

If you have something to add or my solutions are not the best, please let me know, and I will update this post.

Answer (score 0):

For the

> Unrecognized options "naming_strategy, auto_mapping, mappings" under
> "doctrine.orm"

error, try to add the configurations in orm.entity_managers instead of in orm in your config/packages/doctrine.yaml, something like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '5.7'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        #naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        #auto_mapping: true
        #mappings:
        #    App:
        #        is_bundle: false
        #        type: annotation
        #        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
        #        prefix: 'App\Entity'
        #        alias: App

        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    SonataUserBundle: ~
                    FOSUserBundle: ~
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
```

This is working with Symfony 4.4. Maybe this can help someone... I spent some hours with that error :/